# BASH find files with ñ in name

Tags: regex, bash, find, quoting

Already tried multiple solutions around but none seems to work.

For example if I try the next command it works as expected

```
find . -type f -name *x*
```

it returns:

./alphabet/output/b/box.jpg

./alphabet/output/t/taxi.jpg

but if I try any special character in the Spanish alphabet the command doesn't work

```
find . -type f -name *ñ*
```

The results are empty.

If I try

```
find . -type f -name *n*
```

then it shows also the filenames with the special character ñ

Also it doesn't work if I try to set the LANG variable for the command

```
LANG=C find . -type f -name *ñ*
```

or with regex

```
LANG=C find . -type f -name *.jpg -regex '.*[ñ].*'
```

Comment: A simple `find . -type f -name *ñ*` works for me on macOS. What OS are you using?

Comment: Mac OSX El Capitan Region set to USA, and export variables in ~/.bash_profile 
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

Comment: Try to use grep instead

Comment: find . -type f | grep ñ doesn't work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Part of this is stolen from a [previous answer of mine](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10476/how-to-enter-special-characters-so-that-bash-terminal-understands-them).)

Unicode allows some accented characters to be represented in several different ways: as a "code point" representing the accented character, or as a series of code points representing the unaccented version of the character, followed by the accent(s). For example, "ñ" could be represented either precomposed as U+00F1 (UTF-8 0xc3b1, Latin small letter n with tilde) or decomposed as U+006E U+0303 (UTF-8 0x6ecc83, Latin small letter n + combining tilde).

OS X's HFS+ filesystem requires that all filenames be stored in the UTF-8 representation of their fully decomposed form (with a few exceptions that aren't relevant here). In an HFS+ filename, "ñ" MUST be encoded as 0x6ecc83.

When you type "ñ" on the keyboard, it uses the composed form U+00F1 (0xc3b1). You can see this with a hex dump:

```
$ echo ñ | xxd
00000000: c3b1 0a                                  ...
```

(note: the "0a" is a newline at the end of the "line" of output from `echo`.) But when you use it in a filename on a MacOS Extended volume, it gets converted to the decomposed form U+006E U+0303 (0x6ecc83):

$ touch ñ
$ ls | xxd
00000000: 6ecc 830a                                n...

In a UTF-8 locale these two different representations should be considered the same character, but apparently the `find` in macOS doesn't do this right:

```
$ LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 find . -name '*ñ*'
$ LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 find . -name '*n*'
./ñ
$ LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 find . -name 'n?'
./ñ
```

In the second and third commands, `find` is matching against the "n" code point, and treating the combining tilde as a completely separate character that follows it. BTW, note that I put quotes around the match patterns -- this is important because without them the shell will expand it to a list of filenames in the current directory *before* passing it to the `find` command.

The solution? Well, there's an icky option of explicitly using the decomposed form in the pattern. You can do this with bash's `$' ... '` quoting form, which allows hex bytes to be specified with `\x`:

```
$ find . -name $'*n\xcc\x83*'
./ñ
```

But it's actually even worse than that, because starting in macOS High Sierra, Apple's using the new Apple File System (APFS), which allows *both* representations. And since `find` doesn't recognize them as characters, you can't even use a bracket expression like `-name *[ññ]*' to match both of them, you have to use an extended regular expression with`-E`and`-regex`, like this (done on a Mac with APFS):

```
$ touch composed-ñ decomposed-n$'\xcc\x83' unaccented-n
$ ls
composed-ñ  decomposed-ñ    unaccented-n
$ ls | xxd
00000000: 636f 6d70 6f73 6564 2dc3 b10a 6465 636f  composed-...deco
00000010: 6d70 6f73 6564 2d6e cc83 0a75 6e61 6363  mposed-n...unacc
00000020: 656e 7465 642d 6e0a                      ented-n.
$ find -E . -regex $'.*(\xc3\xb1|n\xcc\x83).*'
./composed-ñ
./decomposed-ñ
```

(note that in a regular expression, `.*` is the way you match any sequence of characters, equivalent to `*` in a plain "glob" wildcard pattern.)

Isn't do-it-yourself Unicode support fun?

Comment: lol and I wanted a straight forward way to create full alphabet in Spanish or french, like mkdir -p {a..z} but seems like I will have to stick with mkdir -p {{a..n},ñ,{o..z}} Thanks for the great answer.